# How to tell a class method which variable should be processed

Tags: python

sorry for the noob question. Lets say i have a class which holds 3 lists and a method to combine one of the lists to a string. How can i tell the method which list it should take ? or should i move the method out of the class into a function ?

Here is what i mean:

```
class images():
    def __init__(self, lista, listb, listc):
        self.lista=lista
        self.listb=listb
        self.listc=listc

    def makelist(self):
        items = ""
        for item in self.whateverListIWant:
            items=items+item
        return items

test=images([1,2,3],["b"],["c"])
print (test.makelist(WhichListIWant))
```

Comment: Why not just pass the lists you want to use as parameters?

Comment: side note: `items+item` will raise a TypeError for the first list from your example

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! I am new to classes and so on and thought there is a more capsulated way. Passing the list as parameter is ok ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
class images():
    def __init__(self, lista, listb, listc):
        self.lista=lista
        self.listb=listb
        self.listc=listc

    def makelist(self, param):
        items = ""
        for item in param:
            items= items + str(item)
        return items

test=images([1,2,3],["b"],["c"])
print (test.makelist(test.lista))
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that "class method" (indicated by the decorator [@classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)) is not what you have in your example.  Yours is a standard object method that acts on the object you create, as highlighted by your use of "self" as the first parameter.

The object method acts on the object, and can refer to the data contained within self.  A "class method" would act only on a class, and only use parameters available to that class.

Use of a class method would be something like this:

```
class ClassyImages():
    lista = []
    listb = []
    listc = []

    @classmethod
    def makelist(cls, which):
        if which == 'a':
            the_list = cls.lista
        elif which == 'b':
            the_list = cls.listb
        elif which == 'c':
            the_list = cls.listc
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid value " + str(which))

        return the_list[:]  # returns a soft copy of the list
```

And you would use it as follows:

```
ClassyImages.lista.extend([1,2,3])
ClassyImages.listb.add("b")
ClassyImages.listc.add("c")

print(ClassyImages.makelist("a"))
```

See the difference?  In your example, you're using methods on the instance of an object, which you create.  In this case, we're only using class-level variables, and never using an instance of an object.

However, the nice feature of the `@classmethod` decorator, is you still can use the class method on an object.  So you can also do this:

```
my_classy_object_1 = ClassyImages()
my_classy_object_2 = ClassyImages()

print(my_classy_object_1.makelist("b"))  # prints: ['b']
ClassyImages.listb.add("bb")
print(my_classy_object_1.makelist("b"))  # prints: ['b', 'bb']
print(my_classy_object_2.makelist("b"))  # prints: ['b', 'bb']
```

My answer glossed over what you may really be asking - how to tell it which list to look at.  You can inject the list into the argument, as suggested by [sjaymj64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212995/1404311).  Or you can pass a string or a number into the function, similar to how I did for the class-level makelist.  It's largely up to you - provide whatever way seems most fitting and convenient for letting the logic of makelist choose which of its components to look at.